# RunTimeError: YAML syntax error (Unknown)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have started using and learning *Ruby on Rails*, and I wanted to use *Postgres* instead of *sqlite3*, after a bunch of stuff I went through to install the gem (I'm using *Ruby* 2.1.2 and *Rails* 4.1 in *Ubuntu* 14.04) when I run *Rails* after I create my welcome index page I got this error:

> YAML syntax error occurred while parsing
>   /home/charlie/Documents/Projects/@potsuri/config/database.yml. Please
>   note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are
>   not allowed. Error: (): found character that cannot start any
>   token while scanning for the next token at line 26 column 13

This is what I have in Line 26 column 13

```
database: @potsuri_development
```

This is from line 24 to line 26

```
development:
```

<<: *default
  database: @potsuri_development

I'm new using *Postgres* so I'm not sure how to fix this "syntax error".

Comment: Can you show all database.yml content?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with *Postgres*, but, rather *YAML*/*Ruby*.

I assume by the look of it that you've got a *Ruby* class instance variable you're trying to interpolate into the *YAML* file? I think the issue is that pure *YAML* doesn't know anything about *Ruby*, and so that syntax (the `@` in particular) isn't expected.

The `@` character is reserved in *YAML*, so if you escaped it, i.e. `\@`, it would probably read it in as a literal `@` character, but would likely not interpolate it.

**If** your *YAML* file is being loaded in an *erb* (*Embedded Ruby*) context, and the variable you're trying to interpolate exists, then using *Embedded Ruby* may work to get your value in there, i.e.

```
database: <% @potsuri_development %>
```

**Note**: I did not downvote your question.